# What's the difference between retrospect and hindsight?

Tags: meaning, differences, synonyms

Are they synonyms for looking back on the past that have separate contextual applications or do their meanings differ?

Comment: You can look up their meanings in one or more online dictionaries. It might be interesting to hear about your conclusions.

Answer (score -1):

"Retrospect" quite literally means "look back" in Latin and retains it's meaning in English.

According to [Marriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hindsight), hindsight (noun) is

> perception of the nature of an event after it has happened
> *In hindsight, it's clear there were alternatives.*
> *Hindsight is twenty-twenty.*

while retrospective (noun) is

> 1a(1) : of, relating to, or given to retrospection
>
> (2) : based on memory a retrospective report
>
> b : being a retrospective a retrospective exhibition
>
> 2 : affecting things past : retroactive retrospective laws
>
> 3 : relating to or being a study (as of a disease) that starts with the present condition of a population of individuals and collects data about their past history to explain their present condition

where retrospection (noun) is

> the act or process or an instance of surveying the past

Retrospection can have a more complex meaning compared to hindsight.

You might say

> In hindsight, I shouldn't have eaten the cake.

or

> Retrospectively I shouldn't have eaten the cake.

Hope this helps.